LaTeX Error: No support files for \DocumentMetadata found
! LaTeX Error: No support files for \DocumentMetadata found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16 \DocumentMetadata

Looking at What is \DocumentMetadata? What key-value pairs does it take and when should I use it? I can't determine what I need to add to my TinyTeX distribution to get this to work. Related, and with a full working .tex file: https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/505

You will need the TeX Live packages latex-lab, pdfmanagement-testphase and tagpdf, plus if you are using the development format latex-lab-dev.

For the xmp support only pdfmanagement-testphase is needed.

@UlrikeFischer Well yes but latex-lab is part of the required set for a modern LaTeX install ...

yes you are right, latex-lab is needed too.  I actually wanted to say that tagpdf is only needed if tagging is wanted.

Perfect, thanks. Upvoted and accepted. PS: Now getting ! LaTeX Error: The key 'document/metadata/\PassOptionsToPackage' is unknown error. On \PassOptionsToPackage {breaklinks}{hyperref}.
